# Algorithm Best practice - Generate new apple position in snake?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random, filter

Let's say we're programming a **snake game**.
The game has a **20x20 playing field**. That means there is 400 individual cells.
In snake, a new apple has to generate **on a random unoccupied field/cell**.

There's two common ways to do this

- **Try to place the apple on a random cell, until you hit a free one**
- **Create a list of all free cells, and randomly choose one to place the apple on**

Most people on here would recommend the second approach, because of "better performance". And I thought the same. But after having had statistics in my computer science class, i'm not so sure anymore:

At the start of the game, by logic, the first approach would be faster, because it would very likely instantly find a free cell, whereas the second apprach has a big overhead of creating a list of free cells.
And a little performance test in JS confirms this:

[image: Performance of algorithms at start of game]

At the end of the game - which isn't reached often - when there is only one free field left, the second approach would probably  win in speed, because it would always find the field in 1 go. The first approach needs way more tries - using logarithm we can calulate how many.

50% of the time, it takes less than 276 tries. 90% of the time, it takes less than 919 tries. 99.999999% of the time, it takes less than 5519 tries. And so on. log with base 399/400 of (100-percentage). A few thousands tries more is nothing for a modern computer, so it should only be a little bit slower. This is confirmed by another performance test:

[image: Performance of algorithms at end of game]

0%-4% slower on average ... negligible.

And most of the time, most cells are free, which means the first approach is way faster on average.

Ontop of that, in many languages, for example in C, the first appreach would be shorter in terms of code. There is no overhead for a second array.

This brings me to the conclusion, that **randomly choosing a cell until you find a free one is the best practise** and  creating a list of empty cells is **premate optimization**, and it actually does the opposite (makes performance worse on average because of the added overhead).

Do you agree? Did I miss something?

**What's the best practice in your opinion and why?**

Comment: You pick the method that has the best performance. It seems you measured the performance in depth and that demonstrated that the first approach is more efficient. All the rest is opinion, and that makes this question rather off topic. This question would be more on topic if you would provide the code/algorithm (not as image, but as text) on how you implemented the second approach, as that could be a determining factor on performance.

Comment: If it's 20x20 board performance probably doesn't matter. That said, if you maintain the set of free cells throughout, it's constant time, trading space for speed.

Comment: Having looked at your images (why didn't you post the text yet?), I see your tests are not well designed, and no conclusion should be taken from them. Question has been closed. A pity you didn't update it.

Comment: It's obvious that it is slow if you generate the array each time. If you have a data structure (e.g. a balanced tree with the number of nodes in each subtree) with the empty cells then you have a little overhead for each step adding/removing one cell but you can get the ith empty cell pretty fast. I think all operations could be done in O(logn) (adding, removing and get ith element).

Comment: @maraca
Sure one could do that, but is that much extra code worth the little performance bonus?
Or is the best practise in this case just to write the *shortest possible* or *most readable* code, because the performance difference is negligible? Is taking the solution with the best performance not just premature optimization?
(Ofcourse Best-Practises are always a bit opinion based, sorry if Stackoverflow is the wrong forum for that)

Comment: @FireFuro99 there is no right answer. It depends. Sure readable code is preferred. On the other hand testing random positions could theoretically never get you the free spot, even though the probability is very small (although it still will because it is only pseudo-random).